# `bootstrap_distribution` attribute in scipy.stats.bootstrap() gone?

Tags: python, scipy, bootstrapping

Here is the documentation of `scipy.stats.bootstrap()`, showing that `bootstrap_distribution` is an attribute that should be included in the return object:

[image]
[Link to docs here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.bootstrap.html)

Here is my code that I'm running with, `portfolio['X']` is just a simple column of floats in a pandas dataframe called `portfolio`.

```
from scipy.stats import bootstrap

data = portfolio['X']
data = (data,)
res = bootstrap(data, np.std, n_resamples = 100, confidence_level = 0.95)
print(res.__dir__())
print( res.standard_error)
print( res.confidence_interval)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(res.bootstrap_distribution, bins = 25)
ax.set_title( 'Bootstrap Distribution')
ax.set_xlabel( 'statistic value')
ax.set_ylabel( 'frequency')
plt.show()
```

Here is my output:

```
['confidence_interval', 'standard_error', '__annotations__', '__module__', '__dict__', '__weakref__', '__doc__', '__dataclass_params__', '__dataclass_fields__', '__init__', '__repr__', '__eq__', '__hash__', '__str__', '__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', '__lt__', '__le__', '__ne__', '__gt__', '__ge__', '__new__', '__reduce_ex__', '__reduce__', '__subclasshook__', '__init_subclass__', '__format__', '__sizeof__', '__dir__', '__class__']
0.06917310850614278
ConfidenceInterval(low=0.9366397203338929, high=1.2104462911847762)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-728a3ec52bd0> in <module>
      9 
     10 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
---> 11 ax.hist(res.bootstrap_distribution, bins = 25)
     12 ax.set_title( 'Bootstrap Distribution')
     13 ax.set_xlabel( 'statistic value')

AttributeError: 'BootstrapResult' object has no attribute 'bootstrap_distribution'
```

Answer (score 4):

this attribute seems to be added with 1.10.0 release , make sure your scipy is up to date

Comment: Did `pip install scipy` again and got `Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (1.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.23.0,>=1.16.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (from scipy) (1.21.6)`

Comment: So it says your scipy is (1.7.3) you should upgrade. try `pip install scipy==1.10.0` if it doesnt work maybe upgrade pip first `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Just did both of those, no avail :(

Comment: `Found existing installation: pip 22.0.4 Uninstalling pip-22.0.4: Successfully uninstalled pip-22.0.4 Successfully installed pip-22.3.1` and then `Requirement already satisfied: scipy==1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages (1.10.0)`

Comment: Okay i produced same error.  i installed scipy(1.10.0) as well, and in terminal started python and imported scipy , checked scipy version, everything was fine. However when i started jupyter and did same thing scipy version was different in jupyter. i searched and found reason [link](https://modelpredict.com/importing-packages-in-jupyter-notebook/) . So in jupyter `import sys` and after `!{sys.executable} -m pip install scipy==1.10.0` solved the problem.

Comment: Same error sadly after running that :(
`Attempting uninstall: scipy
    Found existing installation: scipy 1.7.3
    Uninstalling scipy-1.7.3:
      Successfully uninstalled scipy-1.7.3
Successfully installed scipy-1.10.0`

Comment: Am using Google Colab if that helps.

Comment: Okay, after installing (1.10.0) in colab at the top, do Runtime -> Restart Runtime

Comment: Ok now my other dependencies are failing for `import statsmodels.api as sm`: `ImportError: cannot import name '_centered' from 'scipy.signal.signaltools' (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/signal/signaltools.py)`